# Unnamed JSONArray inside JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arrays

Using a web service I'm requesting histogram data. The data is a set of arrays inside an array:

```
[[1375056000000,23.284713745117],[1375142400000,3.809531211853],
[1375228800000,9.6309003829956],[1375315200000,2.7411839962006]]
```

I want to be able to store the key pair values in a Hash Map. Usually I would iterate through a JSONArray and access objects using jsonObject.getInt("whatever"), but in this case I can't. Not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create JSONArray object from your JSON string and then iterate using getJSONArray(int index) method. Finally use getDouble(int index) and getLong(int index) to retrieve values from inner arrays.

in your example:

```
JSONArray a1 = new JSONArray("[[1375056000000,23.284713745117],[1375142400000,3.809531211853]]");
for (int i=0; i<a1.length(); i++) {
 JSONArray a2 = a1.getJSONArray(i);
 long v1 = a2.getLong(0);
 double v2 = a2.getDouble(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = "[[1375056000000,23.284713745117],[1375142400000,3.809531211853],[1375228800000,9.6309003829956],[1375315200000,2.7411839962006]]";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getLong(0); //do something with the key
    jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(1); //do something with the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourJsonArray;
JSONArray root = new JSONArray(yourJsonArray);
int rootSize = root.length();
for (int i = 0, i < rootSize; i++) {
  JSONArray inner = root. getJSONArray(i);
  long firstChildren = inner.getLong(0);
  double secondChildren = inner.getDouble(1);


}
```